# What is the difference between the suffixes 面 and 边?

Tags: difference

What is the difference between 面 and 边 when they are used as suffixes, e.g. 前面 and 前边? Is one preferred over the other? Please provide examples of their different usages in both written and spoken Chinese.

Comment: See this answer : http://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/5898/133

Comment: Yeah, it is a duplicate. Sorry about that, I didn't see it because in the question they use traditional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If solo 边 means the side of something.
Solo 面 means surface of something.

前面 and 前边 has no difference because it comes from different accent like beijing or sichuan accent.

前面 is more hand-writting and 前边 could be used more in some cities like sichuan for accent use . All in all , both are ok in spoken language and writing . Just like 'Hello' and 'Hi' , and a little bit similar to 'old' and 'auld'

Any more questions?

Comment: "Just like 'Hello' and 'Hi' , and a little bit similar to 'old' and 'auld'" - no?